# Add rich content field in Folder SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to put some rich content into a folder field, for this I created a **Content type** that inherits from folder and then I added to my Documents library, the field's type I choose is multiple lines of text and then I select enhanced text, but after when I try to fill the field I dont get the option for it like so:

[image]

What I get looks like this:

[image]

am I doing something wrong? how can I solve it? I would appreciate some help,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The RichTextEditor (the one you created) is only supported in IE browsers:

> An example of functionality that is available in a more limited form
>   would be our "rich text" fields.  In our current release, SharePoint
>   provides a rich text editor with an easy to use rich text toolbar.  To
>   do so, we took advantage of some IE-specific functionality available
>   at the time.  Unfortunately, we weren't able to find room in our
>   schedule for the new version to convert our rich text toolbar to use a
>   more cross-browser compatible technology.  So instead, we're letting
>   end users type in "safe" HTML tags in the rich text fields to achieve
>   the same rich text effects.

Comment: thanks for your replay, when i go into my IE browser i get the same result, the toolbar doestn´t appear, but when I try with a custom list the toolbar works just fine, why happen this? i did a wrong config?, is this a bug with folder rich text fields ? thanks

Comment: RichTextEditor does only work in the list (table), not when you go into the element.

Comment: To provide more details, this is due to the use of the currentStyle object when referencing dom element properties (specifically the richtext textarea element).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231(v=vs.85).aspx

This can be found in the form.js file as outlined in the following blog: 

http://sharepointerz.blogspot.com/2012/07/sharepoint-rich-text-input-control.html